# How do I randomly pick up rows from dataframe until they become a specific value, and then show picked up rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this.

```
test_dict={}
for i in range(1,10):
    test_dict[i]=random.randint(0,100)

test=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict, orient='index').reset_index().set_axis(['Col_1', 'Col_2'], axis=1)
```

I want to randomly pick up rows from this "test" and want to combine Col_2 values until the sum exceeds 200. And I want to show which rows were picked up as a dataframe.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Shuffle and cumsum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little testing this turned out to be the fastest, most consistent and general way to do what you ask:

```
rows_idx = test.index
idx = []
checksum = 0
# Repeat until condition is satisfied
while checksum <= 200:
    add = np.random.choice(rows_idx)
    idx.append(add)
    checksum += test.loc[add, "Col_2"]
new_test = test.loc[idx,:]
```

If you want the results to stop strictly before 200, replace the last line with:

`new_test = test.loc[idx[:-1],:]`

If you do not want to allow for repeated sampling use this modified `while`

```
while checksum <= 200:
    add = np.random.choice(rows_idx)
    if add not in idx:
       idx.append(add)
       checksum += test.loc[add, "Col_2"]
```

## Testing

(I am comparing with Anurag's solution which extremely nice and minimal; also it's very fast). Note that with large dataframes using `df.sample` in loops generally requires more time than saving the index and sampling from it.

```
import time
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 10000000 # beware: BIG NUMBER
test_dict={}
for i in range(1, n):
    test_dict[i]=random.randint(0,100)

test=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict, orient='index').reset_index().set_axis(['Col_1', 'Col_2'], axis=1)

# Anurag's
t1 = time.time()
new_test1=test.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
index=new_test1['Col_2'].cumsum().le(200).idxmin()
new_test1=test[:index]
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)

# Check
new_test1["sum"] = new_test1["Col_2"].cumsum()
new_test1

# While loop
t1 = time.time()
rows_idx = test.index
idx = []
checksum = 0
while checksum <= 200:
    add = np.random.choice(rows_idx)
    if add not in idx:
        idx.append(add)
        checksum += test.loc[add, "Col_2"]
new_test2=test.loc[idx[:-1],:]
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)

# Check
new_test2["sum"] = new_test2["Col_2"].cumsum()
new_test2
```

Comment: Wow. this is incredible! Thanks, luco00, and everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.sample()` in a loop, although the rows would change each time.

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    rand_df = df.sample(i)   
    if rand_df["Col2"].sum() > 200:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = test
sample_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(test)):
    row = df.sample(1)
    df = df.drop(row.index)
    sample_df = sample_df.append(row)
    if sample_df.Col_2.sum() > 200:
        break
```